# Flutter Beamer navigation back

Tags: flutter, navigation, flutter-beamer

I used [Beamer](https://pub.dev/packages/beamer) package for navigation in our flutter project. Once navigating to page1/2/3 pages and if again called beamToNamed('/page1'), then only url is changing but screen is not changing. Screen shots attached(Logo removed in app bar)
So any solution?
[image]
After changing URL through side menu
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is dealing with this, I had a similar issue. Basically how I resolved it was by giving each route a unique ValueKey

```
 '/products/:product': (context, state, data) {
          final product = state.pathParameters['product']!;
          return BeamPage(
            key: ValueKey('Product-$product-${DateTime.now()}'),
            title: 'A Product - $product',
            popToNamed: '/product3',
            type: BeamPageType.scaleTransition,
            child: Product(
              title: product,
            ),
          );
        },
```

The  `key: ValueKey('Product-$product-${DateTime.now()}')` is what resolved the issue of navigating to and fro for me